# how to change the origin to center of the canvas in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Below is the function to draw the axes on a canvas
here i cannot understand the statement  `canvas1.configure(scrollregion=(-x_origin, -y_origin, x_origin, y_origin))`  how scrollregion works.

```
def draw_axes(canvas1):
    canvas1.update()
    x_origin = canvas1.winfo_width() / 2
    y_origin = canvas1.winfo_height() / 2
    canvas1.configure(scrollregion=(-x_origin, -y_origin, x_origin, y_origin))
    canvas1.create_line(-x_origin, 0, x_origin, 0, fill='black')
    canvas1.create_line(0, -y_origin, 0, y_origin, fill='black')
```

According to me it should be +x_origin not -x_origin because it is shifting in +ve X direction 
But when I tried my logic I cannot get my desired  output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollregion` has nothing to do with the origin. All it does is affect the area of the virtual canvas that can be scrolled into view. Of course, you can scroll the canvas to make 0,0 appear at the center or bottom right or anywhere else, but x coordinates will still go to the right and y coordinates will still go down rather than up.

Setting the `scrollregion` also doesn't cause anything to scroll. For scrolling to happen you must call the `xview` and/or `yview` methods to scroll within the scrollable region.

The first two coordinates of the `scrollregion` must define the upper-left corner of the scrollable area, and the second two coordinates represent the bottom-right coordinates. If you reverse them, the behavior is somewhat undefined.

This is the official documentation for `scrollregion`:

> Specifies a list with four coordinates describing the left, top, right, and bottom coordinates of a rectangular region. This region is used for scrolling purposes and is considered to be the boundary of the information in the canvas.

Here's an example of how to get 0,0 to appear at the center of the canvas:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, background="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_oval(-5,-5,5,5, fill="red")
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(-200,-200, 200, 200))
canvas.xview_moveto(.5)
canvas.yview_moveto(.5)

root.mainloop()
```